# YAJGCQ Yet Another Java Generics vs. Collections Q

Tags: java, generics, collections

With solid C++ in my back some Java concepts are not 100% clear.

```
List<SomeInterface> list = new ArrayList<SomeImplementation>;
```

This is 100% clear needs no explanation - but it has consequences...

```
interface Drivable {...}
class Car implements Drivable  {...}
class Bike implements Drivable  {...}
class Skateboard implements Drivable  {...}

class MyGarage{
List<Driveable> myRides;

public void addRides( List<Driveable> rideList ){...}
```

Is not callable with `List<Car>`. However I can add Cars to myRides by:

```
public void addCars( List<Car> carList ){
myRides.addAll( new List<Driveable>( carList ) );
```

**Q1: Is this a good idea?**

I would really want something like the first function to work. By doing something that corresponds to C++ `const&` and adding **a copy of** the incoming carList to myRides I am thinking carList would be protected from illegal access. My hopes of adding `final` as a function argument were crushed.

**Q2: Is there some way to make a fully callable `addRides(List<Driveable> rideList)` work?**

Nor is overloading ( `List<Car> List<Bike> etc` ) legal.

And yes I can make this work by adding separate functions `addBikes() addCars etc` or I could do `new List<Drivable>` at each point of call. But I am hoping for something sleeker.

**Q3: Any suggestions?**

Thanks a lot!
Adam

Comment: The PECS (Produces: `extends`; Consumes: `super`) acronym is definitely worth memorizing.  It is a rule you should follow whenever making a function that takes generics.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **addRides** method should be like this:

```
public void addRides(Collection<? extends Drivable> c)
```

When in doubt about generics usage, look for the collection interfaces in **java.util**, they have lots of examples, what you want to do is the same as what **[Collection.addAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)** does.

Comment: Thanks. Clear and fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

A1. For better protection, you can wrap your List with `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

A2. You need `public void addRides( List<? extends Driveable> rideList ){...}`, since `rideList` can contain *anything that extends Driveable*.

A3. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcard types for the generic parameter. The declaration would be

```
addRides(List<? extends Driveable> list);
```

This accepts a List of Car, Skateboard, Bike, or any other Driveable, and will compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by parametizing your method as such:

```
public class MyGarage{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGarage garage = new MyGarage();
        garage.addRides(new ArrayList<Car>(4));
        garage.addRides(new ArrayList<Bike>(4));
    }

    List<Driveable> myRides;

    public <T extends Driveable> void addRides( List<T> rideList ){
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Which basically declares that your method will accept any List of Objects T, such that T extends from Driveable. I would recommend reading [this excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) which describes Java Generics from the point of view of producers and consumers.

Answer (score 0):

The question that you did not ask should have been on the very first line of code

```
List<SomeInterface> list = new ArrayList<SomeImplementation>;
```

> Why does this not compile?

The reason it does not is the same reason that you need `public void addRides( List<? extends Driveable> rideList )`

Comment: The reason that it does not compile is 100% clear which is precisely why I did not ask that question! And that statement was there to establish what I do know, and what is beyond my knowledge of generics.

Comment: Sorry for my cryptic answer. The reason it does not compile is that a a `List<SomeImplementation>` cannot be assigned to `List<SomeInterface>`. Similarly `List<Car> carList` cannot be bound to `List<Driveable>` parameter of `addRides`. In both cases you need type constraints, e.g. `List<? extends SomeInterface> list = new ArrayList<SomeImplementation>`

Comment: Your answer was not cryptic. It was almost impolite. And I DO know the reason. I knew it all the time. I was asking something else.